# How to connect a HTC android phone to the pc as debugging device

Tags: debugging, synchronization, android

I'd like to connect a HTC Desire to the pc ONLY as debugging device.
Every time I plug the cable in it searches for the HTC Sync software on the pc, and it takes a looong time until finally a message appears on the phone like "no HTC Sync found, ... please install...". After that, the phone is available to eclipse for debugging. But how can I avoid that everlasting searching process?

Comment: So what was the problem? You've accepted my answer but I am really curious why you had the problem.

Comment: Well, I still don't know exactly why I have to wait for HTC Sync each time I connect the phone and I'm not really satisfied with all the answers given here. My connection works perfectly, there's no problem with the drivers. I just wanted to know if anyone else also got into trouble with HTC Sync. But it seems I'm the only one who's annoyed by that search process. So I decided to try installing the HTC Sync software. If you encounter another way to solve this, I'd be glad if you let me know...

Comment: Usually in such difficult cases problem is caused not by a program you use use directly. In that particular case, the problem might be caused by some application you've installed on your HTC. Check also Android Logcat, maybe there you'll find a clue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is copied from [this page](http://www.waxinlyrical.com/node/10). Works for me very well. Just remember to follow procedure described at Android documentation how to connect devices for debugging.

The HTC desire works with the v3 version of the ADB drivers - no HTC Sync installation needed. Add these lines to android_winusb.inf:

[Google.NTx86]
;HTC Desire
%SingleAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_0BB4&PID_0C87
%CompositeAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_0BB4&PID_0C87&MI_01

[Google.NTamd64]
;HTC Desire
%SingleAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_0BB4&PID_0C87
%CompositeAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_0BB4&PID_0C87&MI_01

Comment: Thanks, I know that I don't need to install HTC Sync! As I wrote, my only problem is that on the htc desire, there are only four options "HTC Sync", "charge only", "harddisk", "usb-connection (mobile network)". None of that options works for debugging except "HTC Sync". If I choose it, the "Android Device Chooser" finds the phone, but the phone searches for the HTC software on the pc...

Comment: Or does the solution you gave mean, that the phone doesn't do the search? I'll try it...

Comment: Well I tried...that doesn't change anything... I still have to wait until the search has finished

Comment: For me "Charge only" options works. As far I remember "Disk drive" also worked. Without above modification Android SDK usb driver wasn't able to find my HTC Desire. So I had two options: (1) install HTC Sync on my PC (2) fix Android usb driver.

Comment: Perhaps you have an HTC driver back end installed that you need to remove, so that it stops looking for front end sync software?

Comment: Thanks.. but as I never installed HTC Sync on that pc, only the ADB drivers v3 ...so I think there should be no problem. I tried to select "charge only" option: If I start my app out of eclipse with "Run as" and "Android Application" , the Android Device Chooser opens and doesn't show any running devices, only the emus...:-/

Answer (score 1):

Try to select "Charge only" connection mode as default for you device. Right now it looks like you've selected something to sync by default.

Settings -> Connection to PC -> Default connection type

Comment: Thanks, but did you ever try that? If you choose the "charge only" option no adroid device is found!

Comment: Well I usually do not use Windows. But on Linux that definitely works. Also I remember that when I've tried that with Window my Desire hadn't worked with SDK driver until I install something from device flashcard. Probably HTC has their own driver or you need just to install that sync app to get it working.

Comment: http://myhtcdesire.com/tutorials/how-to-install-the-adb-driver-on-windows here is manual on how to install drivers for HTC desire. At the end there is link to alternative drivers I guess.

Answer (score 0):

In Android 2.2 its Settings -> Applications -> Development -> USB Debugging (Enable).

Comment: I know that - of course, USB debugging is enabled, and it works (as I wrote above). But it searches for HTC Sync every time!