# Android installing application from eclipse not working

Tags: java, android, eclipse, installation, apk

Since now I have always used an emulator because I didn't have a test device. But now I got a phone (htc wildfire s), I have enabled USB debugging and installed the google usb driver from the sdk manager. I have read that Eclipse should automatically install it on the phone if its connected to the usb when you run it as android application. When I ran it as android application it stills runs the emulator and nothing new is installed on the phone.

Phone version is currently : 2.3.3 (API 10)

And application :

```
android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

Comment: check the target version and min sdk version in app

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4099593/how-to-connect-a-htc-android-phone-to-the-pc-as-debugging-device

Comment: Switch Perspective from windows->open Perspective ->DDMS than connect your phone. if you are not see there your phone than you need to check device manager and install driver manually to your system. And make sure that you check USB debugging from your phone.

Comment: inside of eclipse find the 'devices' window view and see if it lists your device in there. If not then you don't have the adb drivers set up properly. Another way to test is go to `platform-tools` folder inside your sdk and run the cmd `adb devices` you should see an entry for you device, if not then your drivers are not set up properly.

Comment: @FoamyGuy my phone is not listed you're right. how do i install the correct drivers? I have them installed already and did it through sdk manager. had only one choice : google usb drivers

Comment: @user1880779 it varries by device how you have to install it. One way to find out is search for something like "how to root [device name]" Look for an XDA thread, the first set of instructions will almost certainly be to get adb drivers working, they are generally pretty good about laying it out step by step how to get the drivers installed and working for each device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had faced a similar problem before. I was using a samsung phone instead.
When i installed samsung Kies, the eclipse(or my PC for that matter) recognized the phone.

Try installing HTC Sync on your development machine.
http://www.htc.com/help/in/howto_iframe.aspx?id=109074&type=1&p_id=423

This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to fix this:

1- From the package explorer view right click on your project.

2- In the list there is an option debug as.

3- In debug as ... Debug Configurations.

4- Chose Android Application from the lift part of the window.

5- In the right part there are multiple tabs, select target.

6- In Development Target Selection Mode .. select Always Prompt to pick device.

and then debug again

Comment: yes I did that unfortunately my phone is not listed. how do i installed correct drivers?

Comment: Please follow this link http://www.bluelight.ru/vb/threads/650467-Android-SDK-HTC-Wildfire-S-USB-driver

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, go into Window>Show View>More and select Devices. If your device is not showing, and you have indeed enabled USB debugging on the device, then the driver is not installed. Check your phone model online and download the needed drivers.

Comment: Phone is not listed in the Devices. Only emulator is listed.

Comment: usb driver is installed i don't know where to find the "correct" one

Comment: I have stated it in my question, I have fixed the problem with installing HTC sync